# How can i create an appointment booking that can limit the bookings in a day

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How can i create an appointment booking that can limit the bookings in a day for example there are only 50 slots available for todays appointment and when you reached the limit you cant pick that date anymore

Comment: Before every new event is created, check for the total number of events created for that day. If it is less than 50, allow creating a new event or else show error that maximum bookings for that day are done.

Comment: Use a library like FullCalendar.js. Using it, you can then block certain days.